# package.json: what is the difference between & and &&?

Tags: node.js, package.json

Title pretty much says it all, but I'd also like to know if these commands work or behave differently depending upon the OS.

example1:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "babel -d serverbuild ./server",
    "exe": "node ./serverbuild/index.js",
    "start": "npm run build && npm run exe"
}
```

example2:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "babel -d serverbuild ./server",
    "exe": "node ./serverbuild/index.js",
    "start": "npm run build & npm run exe"
}
```

Given these examples portions of a package.json, what would be the difference between npm run start?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

When using `&&`, the first command will run, and if it does not error, the second command will run. It's like a logical AND.

Using `&`, however, will run a command in the background. So in your second package.json, `npm run build` will start running in the background and then `npm run exe` will run as well regardless of what happens to the first command.

Comment: Thank you, I had this same perception of it at first glance but was not sure.